# What is the fastest way to calculate product of $a\times (a+1)\times (a+2)\times \ldots \times(a+n)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there any formula? I tried something like this:

$a(a+1)(a+2)..(a+n) = a^{(n+1)} \times (1+1)(1+2)...(1+n)$

I know there must be simple solution but i'm lost

Comment: Hello. Is $a$ an integer?

Comment: For any $a$ this can be written as a quotient of gamma functions, and that's about as simple as it will be.

Comment: Your proposed  factoring method is incorrect.  You could get $a^{n+1}\times \left(1+\frac 1a\right)\times \left(1+\frac 2a\right)\times \cdots \times \left(1+\frac na\right)$ but I don't see how that helps.

Comment: this can be related to factorials due to the relationship between $\prod$ and $\Gamma(x)$ and $x!$

Comment: If you have access to gamma function it will be $\frac{\Gamma(a+n+1)}{\Gamma(a)}$

Comment: Fastest in what sense?  By hand?  On a computer?

Comment: @mathreadler  I think it should be $\dfrac{\Gamma(a+n+1)}{\Gamma(a)}$.

Comment: Yes a is an integer.

Comment: @Batominovski yep you are right, I was too quick to type.

Comment: I hope the author isn't searching for a method to compute $(n-1)! \bmod n$ ;)

Comment: The fastest way on a computer.

Comment: Take a look at fast factorial algorithms here, as they should nicely generalize to rising factorials: http://www.luschny.de/math/factorial/FastFactorialFunctions.htm

Otherwise the comments are suggesting some truly awful ideas, like evaluating (a+n)!/(a-1)!, which is both numerically unstable and twice the effort.

Comment: Are you interested in minimising the processing time - i.e. a computing problem? Or are you interested in minimising the time you'd need to spend pressing buttons? In the latter case you'd want to use a standard calculator function and factorials would do it: (a + n)! / (a - 1)!

Comment: "I know there must be simple solution"  Why? I dont see any reason this should be easy. " $a(a+1)(a+2)..(a+n) = a^{(n+1)} \times (1+1)(1+2)...(1+n)"  That's obviously not true.  $a(a+1)(a+2)..(a+n) = a^{(n+1)} \times (1+\frac1a)(1+\frac 2b)...(1+\frac na)$.  Which is $> a^{n+1}$.  If you have a reasonable estimate of $ (1+\frac1a)(1+\frac 2b)...(1+\frac na)$ that could help but ... I don't see any reasonable wat to estimate it.

Comment: @AlexR. I don't think it's so very awful if you use log-gamma and exponentiate.

Comment: @mathreadler: At least for integers: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Factorial%5B10%5E100%5D%2FFactorial%5B10%5E100-1%5D

So human intelligence still trumps computers. (Note that n=10^{100} is the upper bound where WolframAlpha fails, on a typical calculator it'll be much lower)

Comment: @AlexR I don't think you read what I wrote. I did not propose to do that calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments you can calculate$$\frac{\Gamma(a+n+1)}{\Gamma(a)}$$

There seem to be very many ways to calculate $\Gamma$, for example [series expansion of log-gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#The_log-gamma_function):

$$\log (\Gamma(z)) \approx z\log(z)-z-\frac 1 2 \log\left(\frac z {2\pi}\right)+\frac{1}{12z}+\frac{1}{360z^3}+\frac{1}{1260z^5}+\cdots$$

Then you can finish by using

$$\frac{\Gamma(z_1)}{\Gamma(z_2)}=\exp(\log (\Gamma(z_1)) - \log (\Gamma(z_2)))$$

Answer (score 2):

You could call it the [Pochhammer symbol](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PochhammerSymbol.html) $(a)_{n+1}$. That's just notation rather than calculation, but many CAS's will have it.  For example, in Maple it's **pochhammer(a,n+1)**.  In Mathematica (or Wolfram Alpha) it's **Pochhammer[a, n + 1]**.